# Google Charts Line Graph all over the place

Tags: charts, google-visualization

First time working with some Graph JS Library.

I am using Google Charts which is pretty cool but my graph is all over the place - https://jsfiddle.net/gcwebsites/5ae9fhj0/1/

This is my script code with my array/loop.

`
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

```
                    function drawBasic() {

                        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                        data.addColumn('number', 'X');
                        data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');

                        data.addRows([
                            <?php foreach($daily_temperature_array as $dtemp): ?>[<?php echo $dtemp['time']; ?>,<?php echo $dtemp['temp']; ?>],<?php endforeach; ?>
                        ]);

                        var options = {
                            hAxis: {
                            title: 'Time'
                            },
                            vAxis: {
                            title: 'Temperature'
                            }
                        };

                        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('temperaturechart'));

                        chart.draw(data, options);
                    }
                </script>`
```

I am trying to create a line graph of time and temperature from weather station data I have in a database query.

Anyone able to assist and see why my graph is all over the joint?

Thanks.

Replicated the original Google Code https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/ / https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#examples and was expecting a perfect line graph.......

Comment: I resolved it by changing some of the column parameters:
`data.addColumn('string', 'time');
data.addColumn('number', 'temp');`

Comment: if you want to use a number column instead of string, just sort the data table before drawing the chart --> [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WhiteHat/yhv0gpcm/)